# Jquery UI Tabs - Centre the whole Div / container

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, tabs

I am using Jquery UI Tabs (https://jqueryui.com/tabs/#vertical) . I want the whole container to be in the centre of the page. I don't mean the content of the open tabs or the clickable tab text. I mean the outer most container that has everything inside it.

There are many examples on Google to align the tabs or the content, but I can't find anything on how to align the main div.

So far this is what I have tried:

```
div.otabs {
align-content:center;
width:300px;
height:300px;
border:1px solid #555;
position:absolute;
align-items:center;
justify-content:center;
top:10px;
left:10px;

 }
```

I have tried this code on the actual tabs div and also added my own div outside the tabs div, but the tabs container stays left aligned. Can anyone suggest something?

```
<div id="otabs" class="otabs">
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
<li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
<li><asp:LinkButton runat="server" href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor        </asp:LinkButton></li>
</ul>
<div id="tabs-1">
<h2>Content heading 1</h2>
<p>Proin elit arcutempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec tempus lectus.</p>
</div>
<div id="tabs-2">
<h2>Content heading 2</h2>
<p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis . Suspendisse sed ligula in ligula suscipit aliquam. Praesent in .</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since, you're already making use of `position:absolute` on the container. You just need these 3 lines of code to center the container *vertically and horizontally*: (This enables you to not have to change your display or any other CSS properties in anyway if not required)

```
transform:translate(-50%,-50%); 
  left:50%;
  top:50%;
```

```css
body{

}
div.otabs {
  align-content: center;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #555;
  position: absolute;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
  left:50%;
  top:50%;
  
}
```

```html
<div id="otabs" class="otabs">
  <div id="tabs">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
      <li>
        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor </asp:LinkButton>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
      <h2>Content heading 1</h2>
      <p>Proin elit arcutempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec tempus lectus.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
      <h2>Content heading 2</h2>
      <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis . Suspendisse sed ligula in ligula suscipit aliquam. Praesent in .</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, your code works with the extra otabs outer div. But ideally I would like the actual tabs to get centred and just remove the otabs. Is that possible?  I tried doing that and the code has no effect on the tabs div.

Comment: @SANM2009 Oh you need the tab divs centered?

Comment: I think it is sorted. I added class=tabs to the tabs div and it is working now.

Comment: Alright :) You could even just add margin:0 auto; to your tabs div and it would center itself inside the div.otabs. But you have to make sure that its not taking the entire width of the div.otabs or even it is centered it wont look like it is.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `position:absolute`, then add `display: block;` and `margin: auto`.
[CSS Margin](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp) auto will make the browser calculate it (all margins with same size).

```
div.otabs {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    align-content:center;
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    border:1px solid #555;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content:center;
    top:10px;
    left:10px;
}
```